# PHP shows blank pages

Tags: php, apache

I am using Apache on Ubuntu, and every PHP page shows nothing. However, other files, such as images are displayed normally. What should I do?

Comment: Need more information. Start by checking your error log. Probably /var/log/apache2/error.log .

Comment: Question is not clear enough??

Answer (score 2):

Start by changing the file extension of one of your php files to **.php4** or **.php5**.

If you still see a blank page you might have errors in your code, to debug  insert the following code at the top of your php files:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);  // will report any errors your code may have
ini_set("display_errors", 1); // will display those errors
```

Still seeing a blank page ? If you're on shared hosting please ignore the following step and report the problem to your hosting provider.
 
 
It's possible that php isn't installed correctly with Apache, to install it on Ubuntu run:

```
sudo apt-get install php5
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Please Let me know if it worked.